# XSLT Multi level Filtering syntax

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to structure my html report so I process my XML as below. I am struggling to get the syntax right. 
I can get the outer cf_fixinpatch value in a variable but can't use this value in the "select" to filter further in section. I know what do one I have the records... Thanks

Output Html

```
<html>
<cf_fixinpatch> <= loop through unique values
    write cf_fixinpatch header
   <section>    <= loop through unique values
    write section header
      <All records matching cf_fixinpatch and section values>  <= loop
       Write out various aspects of the Result node
   </section>
<cf_fixinpatch>
</html>
```

Input XML

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Results> <= many repeat nodes
    <bug_id>64252</bug_id>
    <name>SCADA</name>
    <short_desc>[FUNCTIONALITY]: Server name is not correct in SOE System Message</short_desc>
    <bug_status>VERIFIED</bug_status>
    <resolution>FIXED</resolution>
    <bug_severity>normal</bug_severity>
    <section>Alarms</section>
    <release_title>Some SOE items that reference an alarm server do not use its proper name</release_title>
    <release_notes>Such events now use "ClusterName_ServerName" when referencing alarm servers.</release_notes>
    <cf_fixinpatch>v7.50 SP1 Patch 5</cf_fixinpatch>
  </Results>
  ...
</DocumentElement>
```

NB: Using Windows msxl which does not support 2.0 (and if too hard, can move to 2.0), I can do something like

```
<xsl:variable name="unique-list" select="/DocumentElement/Results[not(cf_fixinpatch=following::Results/cf_fixinpatch)]" />
 <xsl:for-each select="$unique-list">
 <xsl:variable name="current_patch" select="cf_fixinpatch" />
   <!-- but don't know how to use this in the next loop -->
 -----------------
<xsl:for-each select="/DocumentElement/Results">
<xsl:if test="not(section = preceding-sibling::section)"> <= cant get to work, if worked i can win or
 <xsl:if test="cf_fixinpatch != Results[position()-1]/cf_fixinpatch">
```

PM 09/05 Feedback - I found a solution but is the hard way to do this so I am providing some feedback

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/DocumentElement/Results">

        <xsl:variable name="thePatch" select="preceding-sibling::Results[1]/cf_fixinpatch"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="($Patches = 'true') and (position() = 1 or cf_fixinpatch != $thePatch)">
            <!-- Write out the Patch Level -->
             <h4 style="color:#d82553">
                <a>
                  <xsl:value-of select="cf_fixinpatch" />
                </a>
            </h4>
        </xsl:if>       

        <xsl:variable name="theSection" select="preceding-sibling::Results[1]/section"></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="(position() = 1) or (section != $theSection)">
             <!-- Write out the Section Information -->
            <h4 style="color:#C75B12;text-index:40px">
                <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="section" />
                </a>
            </h4>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Then record info written out -->
```

Comment: You're trying to use XSLT procedurally, which often is the wrong way to approach a problem.  XSLT is a (nearly) pure functional language that benefits from a different approach. [Edit] your question to show the output XML corresponding to the input and you're more likely to get some help.

Comment: If you trying to group your `Results` elements by their `cf_fixinpatch` value, then in XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique known as Muenchian Grouping. (See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). It might help if you showed your expected output in the case. Thank you!

Comment: I should have mentioned I am creating a html file of information, the Xml is the input.

Comment: The jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html looks useful thanks
Late last night I got something to work (GMT+10) as I could get inline preceding-sibling working in a select (cant get code into comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are grouping the `Results` element first by `cf_fixinpatch` and then, for all those in the same patch, by `section` element. This means you are doing two lots of grouping. To group by just `cf_fixinpatch` you would need this key

```
<xsl:key name="results_by_patch" match="Results" use="cf_fixinpatch" />
```

But to group on `section` values for all `Results` elements in a given group (as opposed to all `Results` in the document), you would need a concatenated key

```
<xsl:key name="results_by_patch_and_section" match="Results" use="concat(cf_fixinpatch, '|', section)" />
```

Try this XSLT that nests one lot of Muenchian grouping inside another:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="results_by_patch" match="Results" use="cf_fixinpatch" />
  <xsl:key name="results_by_patch_and_section" match="Results" use="concat(cf_fixinpatch, '|', section)" />

  <xsl:template match="DocumentElement">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Results[generate-id() = generate-id(key('results_by_patch', cf_fixinpatch)[1])]">
          <h1 style="color:#d82553">
            <xsl:value-of select="cf_fixinpatch" />
          </h1>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('results_by_patch', cf_fixinpatch)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('results_by_patch_and_section', concat(cf_fixinpatch, '|', section))[1])]">
            <h2 style="color:#C75B12;text-index:40px">
              <xsl:value-of select="section" />
            </h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('results_by_patch_and_section', concat(cf_fixinpatch, '|', section))" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Results">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="bug_id" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```